# PCB Copper pour without making Schematic

Tags: copper-pour

I have a problem with ground Copper pour for the PCB.
I'm using [EasyEDA.com](https://easyeda.com) to designing my PCBs.

But because i usually make my PCB **directly without Drawing its schematic** so i can't make the ground Copper pour because there are no GND detected by the system.

So i'm wondering if there are way to Copper pour without drawing the schematic?

Following image just an example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Such a simple design - why not make life easier for yourself and start from a schematic like other any other design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the NET label, for every pad you want to connect to say.. GND :)
Then you can change to pad type if it's a through hole component to attach it to the ground plane.
[image: Example]